# Run command line process as admin Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shell, uac, administrator

I am writing a Qt application that needs to call system programs (`netsh`) and run them as administrator.

However, `QProcess`, `QDesktopServices` and `system()` don't allow me to run the application as administrator (not even with `runas`).

The only solution that I found is to use `ShellExecute`, but it does not even open the program.

**My code is:**

`#ifdef Q_OS_WIN {
    ShellExecute(0, LPCWSTR("runas"), LPCWSTR("netsh wlan start hostednetwork"),                  0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}`

I have also tried to use other options, such as `open` and tried to run other programs, such as Notepad (`notepad.exe`) and Control Panel (`control.exe`), nothing worked.

I have also tried to add an manifest file and nothing was solved.

Do I miss something in my code? (examples are welcome).

Comment: if I remeber right, you will need to require your complete QT program to run as an administrator ( http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46917-How-to-run-application-in-qt-as-administrator ) - then you can start the application by shellexecute/system()

Comment: It is platform-specific feature. Your code is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LPCWSTR("runas") - this is incorrect, you typecast string to widestring, and probably ShellExecute will return error and does not start an application. Specify "L" prefix instead.
Also, you need to split command and parameters, "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" will not work as command name.
Use it like this:

```
ShellExecute(0, L"runas", L"netsh", L"wlan start hostednetwork", 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```